# Copy site but preserve permissions

Tags: linux, drupal

I wanted to copy my Drupal site to another location (VDS), I got full backup from my provider, (in tar.gz), untarred and ungzipped it, deleted some folders, zipped it again in 7zip format, then copied it with sftp to /var/www on VDS and unzipped, but all permissions now are read-only and so Drupal doesn't work at all cause it cannot acess files.

Can anyone tell when I lost my permissions, the right way to migrate to my VDS or (and) how can I manage with my corrupted-permission Drupal now (maybe I just can change them?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read only permission is generally fine for a Drupal site, except for the upload folder (it's nomally called `files` and in can be in `sites/default` or in `sites/YOUR_SITE_CONFIGURATION_FOLDER` or wherever you set it to be in `admin/config/media/file-system`). The `files` folder, and every subfolder it contains must be writable from the web server, so if your web server is running as the www-data user (the standard user for Apache in Ubuntu, other systems may differ) you can for example do

```
chmod -R o+w sites/default/files
chown -R www-data sites/default/files
```